# The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'.

getting an error in this part `auth.currentUser`:

```dart
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User user = await auth.currentUser();
String uid = user.uid;

await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('data')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('data')
        .doc();
```

Comment: try to define User user = await auth.currentUser(); with nullable like User ? user = await auth.currentUser(); and then use String uid = user!.uid;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try;

```
 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User user = await auth.currentUser;
String uid = user!.uid;
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data').doc(uid).collection('data').doc();
```

Answer (score 2):

`User` instance could be `null` and explicit conversion with the null assertion operator (`user!.uid`) is not a good practice, because it may cause a runtime exception.

therefore try this one:

```dart
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final User? user = await auth.currentUser();
final String? uid = user?.uid;

if(user != null && uid != null) {
  // We have already tested 'uid' nullability, so now it is safe to use 'uid!'.
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('data')
          .doc(uid!)
          .collection('data')
          .doc();
} else {
  throw Exception('current user is null.');
}
```